# Pandas Dataframe Groupby and convert into columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with data as follows:

```
Shipment | Customer | Item
  5050   | 130456   | 435
  5050   | 130457   | 436
  5050   | 130458   | 443
  5051   | 130461   | 449
  5051   | 130462   | 449
  5051   | 130463   | 450
  5051   | 130464   | 451
  5052   | 130471   | 463
```

My output should look like

```
Shipment | Customer 1 | Customer 2 | Customer 3 | Customer 4 | Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3 | Item 4 |
 5050    | 130456     | 130457     | 130458     |            | 435    | 436    | 443    |        |
 5051    | 130461     | 130462     | 130463     | 130464     | 449    | 449    | 450    | 451    |
 5052    | 130471     |            |            |            | 463    |        |        |        |
```

Basically I want all the unique shipments as rows and the corresponding customers and items in separate columns. How can I do this? The item and customer should be mapped exactly. There can't be a mismatch.

Edit: I have other columns along with these 3 columns. I want to keep those columns as it is.